# How to select only few plot to output as a pdf in gnuplot

Tags: loops, pdf, output, gnuplot

I'm plotting in a pdf with a double loop like this :

```
set terminal pdf
set output "fichier.pdf"

set datafile separator ","
set title "test"
set grid
set ylabel "y"
set xlabel "x"
set autoscale
set key on inside left top

do for [t1=0:1]{
do for [t2=0:1]{
plot 'AirEauG10VEtHDebit1mLMinute.dat' using ($1):($2/(80.4/($2+t1)**2)) title 'e='.t1
replot 'a.dat' using ($1):($2/(80.4/($2+t2)**2)) title 'e='.t2
}
}

unset output
```

Now, I'm having all the plots. Which are all the graphs one with only one plot, one with the two plots, one with only one plot etc. But I just want, in the pdf, to have the graphs with the two plots. How can I say to gnuplot to only save the graph with the two plots ?

So, instead of having 4 pages (2 with one plot and 2 with two plots), I would like to have only 2 pages (the ones with two plots on it).

Tell me if I'm not clear enough :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `replot` for output to a file! That makes sense only for an interactive plotting terminal.

The `plot` command can have many plots, separated by a comma:

```
set terminal pdf
set output "fichier.pdf"

set datafile separator ","
f(x, t) = x/(80.4/(x + t)**2)

do for [t1=0:1] {
    do for [t2=0:1] {
        plot 'AirEauG10VEtHDebit1mLMinute.dat' u 1:(f($2, t1)) title 'e='.t1,\
        'a.dat' u 1:(f($2, t2)) title 'e='.t2
    }
}
```